# SQL retrieve yearly repeated event

Tags: mysql, sql, events

How to write a sql statement to retrieve repeated yearly event, which mean retrieve all the event regardless year only match with month and date.

```
Select * from Event where [date] = date ?
```

Comment: What type of sql are you using mysql, tsql, plsql, other?

Comment: Given that you have accepted an answer that uses the mysql `MONTH()` and `DAY()` functions, I have added the mysql tag to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MONTH() and DAY() for this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Event
WHERE
    MONTH([date]) = 12
AND
    DAY([date]) = 25
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DAY() and MONTH() functions on a date field

```
SELECT * FROM Event WHERE MONTH(Date) = '7' AND DAY(Date) = '4'
```

That would get you all events that happen on the 4th of July, regardless of the year.